# How to add loading spinner between two icon button in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have 2 button, connect (power-on.png) button, and disconnect (power-off.png) button. I want to add CircularProgressIndicator() between those 2 button. So, when I click connect button, it show the CircularProgressIndicator() and then change to disconnect, and vice versa. I have try, but it just show me when I click connect button it just show the CirculatProgressIndicator().

This is my code:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
    child: IconButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        if (state == FlutterVpnState.disconnected) {
          setState(() {
            isPressed = true;
          });
        try {
          await FlutterVpn.connectIkev2EAP(
            server: dataAddress,
            username: _usernameController.text,
            password: _passwordController.text,
          );
          setState(() {
            isPressed = false;
          });
        } catch (e) {
          setState(() {
            isPressed = false;
          });
        } else {
          FlutterVpn.disconnect();
          setState(() {
            isPressed = true;
          });
        }
      },
      icon: isPressed
        ? Image.asset(
          state == FlutterVpnState.disconnected
            ? 'assets/images/power-on.png'
            : 'assets/images/power-off.png',
          )
        : CircularProgressIndicator(),
      iconSize: 120,
    ),
  ),
```

This is the screenrecord of my emulator:
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the variable `isPressed`.

When you check if the button has been pressed you stop showing it and show the upload circle, but while the upload is being shown, you don't do anything to check FlutterVpnState.disconnected, so you are never doing that check.

What you would do is something like this:

Check if it is disconnected to show one image or another, once you know that state, you check if it has been clicked to show the upload circle.

```
     state == FlutterVpnState.disconnected
             ? isPressed 
             ? CircularProgressIndicator() 
             : Image.asset(
              'assets/images/power-on.png' ?
              )
             : Image.asset(
              'assets/images/power-off.png')
```

I hope it helped you